# Effective way having a statement execute only once in an infinite function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable `a` that changes its value every time the function runs. I need it to do stuff once `a` equals certain numbers only once, and never do it again. How can I do this?

This is what I have so far, and the problem is that it runs every time `a` equals a certain number, not only once.

```
def function():
    if a == 1:
        // do stuff for 1 once

    if a == 32:
        // do stuff for 32 once

    if a == 10:
        // do stuff for 10 once

while True:
    function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be to use a `set` to keep track of which values have already been seen:

```
seen = set()

def function():
    if a in seen:
        return
    else:
        seen.add(a)

    if a == 1:
        // do stuff for 1 once

    if a == 32:
        // do stuff for 32 once

    if a == 10:
        // do stuff for 10 once

while True:
    function()
```

Comment: Very simple solution. Thank you.